# Need to break down years to match other products years

Tags: sql, reporting-services

- a1c-R 2011-2013
- a1c-F 2009-2013
- a1c-R 2009-2010

I Need to break down the years so they match between kits and rollup properly. Such as 2009-2013 must become 2009-2010, 2011-2013 to make the R kit match up with the F kit and allow them to rollup and be displayed cleaner in SSRS.

How do I go about making the a1c-F become two separate rows so that both would be

- a1c-R 2009-2010
- a1c-R 2011-2013
- a1c-F 2009-2010
- a1c-F 2011-2013

Comment: It tookme a few minutes to understand your request. But I still confused. What are you going to do with other columns of the rows involved?

Comment: What would happened to records like a1c-R 2007-2008 with no matches in a1cF?

Comment: I wish I had enough reputation to just show you an image from SSRS of how it's displaying because that would be much easier.  Instead of grouping the years together it makes them separate entries and makes the roll up look confusing and misleading.  a1cF would just display nothing as there is no part for that year. Everything else that goes with the years should roll up but because the years don't line up such as 2009-2013 vs 2009-2010, 2011-2013 it generates 3 rows instead of two.  As the year ranges increase this problem only becomes worse.

Comment: It would be far easier if you could break the aggregation into yearly increments. This may not work in your case but it would cause less headaches.•a1c-R 2009-2010 
•a1c-R 2010-2011 
•a1c-R 2011-2012 
•a1c-R 2012-2013
 
•a1c-F 2009-2010 
•a1c-F 2010-2011 
•a1c-F 2011-2012 
•a1c-F 2012-2013

Comment: It is possible for me to aggregate the years as you have listed but then I would like to collapse the years based on a common number as I have them in the beginning (2009-2013).  How could I go about that if I had them in yearly increments?  It is a large database and if they were all labeled year by year it would be a massive output

Comment: @h_laessig you could add a link to a image hosted anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpful to return the data with a one to one match based on all years that are contained in the a1c-F code group regardless of data in other code product/groups.

You will always have the data to rollup by each and every year matching your dominant group even if the values in the other groups are null for that year. You do not have to worry about interlacing year ranges in your column or row groups.

```
CODE                YEAR    Value1
a1c-F 2008-2009     2008    2
a1c-F 2009-2010     2009    5
a1c-F 2010-2011     2010    3
a1c-F 2011-2012     2011    2
a1c-F 2012-2013     2012    3
a1c-F 2013-2014     2013    7
...   
a1c-R 2008-2009     2008    NULL
a1c-R 2009-2010     2009    4
a1c-R 2010-2011     2010    4
a1c-R 2011-2012     2011    4
a1c-R 2012-2013     2012    4
a1c-R 2013-2014     2013    NULL
....
a1c-D 2008-2009     2008    NULL
a1c-D 2009-2010     2009    NULL
a1c-D 2010-2011     2010    NULL
a1c-D 2011-2012     2011    NULL
a1c-D 2012-2013     2012    2
a1c-D 2013-2014     2013    NULL
```

If you have a yearly grouping then you cleanly create higher level grouping based on 5 year groups 10 year groups etc, etc.

You could also add to your grouping a condition that states where the year is between a1c-F's First Year and a1c-F's Last year. That would condense all the data to one record per group, based on a1c-F's total year span.